# Migrate maria db to azure sql using azure cli

Tags: mariadb, azure-sql-database, database-migration, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-services

How do I migrate/copy my on-premise Maria db to azure sql using azure cli or azure ps.

Tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-sync-data-between-azure-onprem?toc=%2Fpowershell%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json) but was unable to proceed as it needed 3 db's.

Using SSMA tool I have migrated successfully.

Please let me know if there any way to automate the migration of the database, also it has to be compatible with any environment.

Comment: That link talks about SQL Server, which is different than MariaDB/MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is talked about SQL Database not the MariaDB.
SQL Database server is different from MariaDB.

You can migrate your on-premise MariaDB to Azure Database for MariaDB,see:

Migrate your MariaDB database to Azure Database for MariaDB using dump and restore
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/howto-migrate-dump-restore